# how to set the php variable with javascript value and use that php variable in external php file

Tags: php

`design.php` file:

```
 <script>
    $(".colr_sldr li img").click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var value=src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    <?php $var = "<script>document.write('" + value + "')</script>";?>
     });
    </script>
```

and use this variable in `index.php` file:

```
<?php 
include('design.php');
echo $var;
?>
```

here while i am printing this variable it is getting zero can any one help

Comment: I don't think this can be done unless you're not using ajax!

Comment: long story short : use AJAX for sending javascipt value to php script

Comment: I guess I shouldn't be surprised that people keep asking this quesion. It's pretty basic knowledge, but it does require a good understanding of how web requests (and client/server systems in general) work. Code on the client (ie the browser) runs entirely separately from code on the server, even if they are programmed together, even in the same file. When they're running, they know nothing of each other. In order to have them work together, you have to explicitly get them to communicate with each other. The common name for this in the web world is AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

you can't take var like this in php..

```
$var = "<script>document.write('" + value + "')</script>";?>
```

because **php** is **server side language** ..
and **javascript** is **client side**.

For this you have to use **ajax ,get and  post methods**

Answer (score 1):

the only solution I may know is using  jquery  on client side an sending your variable via ajax :

script.js

```
$('document).ready(function(){
       var myVar="Hello";
      $.post('design.php',myVar);

});
```

and in design.php you have acces to your variable with $_POST
design.php

```
<?php 
   $myVar = $_POST['myVar'];
   echo $myVar;?>
```

please check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more details

or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/